# Using socket.io with memcached in multiple servers (Auto Scaling)

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, socket.io, memcached

I'm using [this memcached package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached) and I'm trying to get data from my server that store my PHP sessions with memcache. Whenever someone enters my website, a value is stored in the variable `$_SESSION["user"]` (used to chat) and I want to get that values to use with `socket.io` (to define who is online and send messages, regardless of the server), because if I am connected to `server 2`, whoever is on `server 1` can't see me online or send me messages, so, I did:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").Server(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(http),
    Memcached = require("memcached"),
    users = {};

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/scripts"));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    var mem = new Memcached("privateipofmymemcachedserver:11211");

    mem.get("user", function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        if(data === false) {
            return console.error("Data no found!");
        }

        console.log("Data: " + data);
    });

    // From client, sended when $(document).ready()
    socket.on("connected", function(data) {
        socket.user = data.user;

        if(!users[socket.user]) {
            users[socket.user] = new Set();
        }
        users[socket.user].add(socket);

        updateUsers();
    });

    // To update online users list
    function updateUsers() {
        io.emit("users", Object.keys(users));
    }
});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8000);

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Server running on 8000!");
});
```

But, when I run the code and go to console, the only thing that returns is:

```
Data: undefined
Data: undefined
Data: undefined
```

How can I "fix" it? Or is there any better way to do this without involving PHP sessions, just with the socket itself and its functions? Using socket or express cookies, perhaps? I also read about Redis, if it is a good option, how could I adapt my code to use it?

Comment: If you are using using elastic beanstalk, look into enabling sticky sessions on your load balancer. This will fix your issue.. 

There is also a way of doing this with a socket.io adapter but [socket.io-memcached](https://github.com/marcofranssen/socket.io-memcached) lib is not maintained anymore it seems. I would recommend you switch to redis if you want to use an [adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis).

Comment: @mkhanoyan That was it, thank you! I found it would not work because with PHP sticky sessions did not work and I had to use memcached ... Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using using elastic beanstalk, look into enabling sticky sessions on your load balancer. This will fix your issue..   There is also a way of doing this with a socket.io adapter but [socket.io-memcached](https://github.com/marcofranssen/socket.io-memcached) lib is not maintained anymore it seems. I would recommend you switch to redis if you want to use an [adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis).
                    – mkhanoyan